# onTouchListener in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` with `onTouchListener` inside a `ViewPager`. Of course the `ImageView`'s listener fires off when I try to change `ViewPager`'s page. Is there a way to prevent it. I guess I need to recognize touch from swipe somehow.

This is the extract of my code :

```
public class ServerDetailFragment extends Fragment implements SimpleGestureListener {
GestureDetector detector;
SimpleOnGestureListener gestures = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.e("TAG", "onFling");
        return true;
    };
};
....


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    detector = new GestureDetector(ServerDetailFragment.this.getActivity(), gestures);

}

....

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_server_detail, container, false);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    myPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_pager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = myPager.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            pagerGraph = (ImageView) myPager.findViewWithTag(myPager.getCurrentItem()).findViewById(R.id.pagerView);
            pagerPb = (ProgressBar) myPager.findViewWithTag(myPager.getCurrentItem()).findViewById(R.id.pagerPb);
            if (init) {

                plotFakeData();

                // Following problematic part is also in ViewPager's onPageChangeListener

                        pagerGraph.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (detector.onTouchEvent(event)) {

                            // some more code here

                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                });

                // myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
            init = false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if you just return `false` from the ImageView's OnTouchListener? This will allow the ViewPager to receive the touch events.

Comment: ViewPager receives events all right.What I want is ImageView not receive attempt to change page.

Comment: Have you tried using a [`SimpleOnGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) to ignore swipe events in the ImageView?

Comment: I tried,but I don't know how to implement gesture detector just for the ImageView.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        onTouch(e);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                    } else {
                    }
                }
            } else {
               // onTouch(e);
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
public void onTouch(MotionEvent e) {
}
}
```

and call them this way:

```
pagerGraph.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {          
public void onTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: That GestureDetector constructor is now deprecated so you may instead construct the listener with activity context and then instantiate the GestureDetector at that point.

Comment: I believe you're absolutely right. But look when the question was asked and when I answered it :) there is no written policy for "what to do when answer gets outdated"...(http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265749/whats-the-policy-on-down-voting-previously-correct-but-now-outdated-answers). I'd love to tell you that if you feel like adding it to my answer go for it - but that is not the right way to go I believe. You could add it as a brand new answer saying - since version 4.X.Y...etc.

Comment: Well if you want to be pedantic about it, that constructor has been deprecated since April 2009 so you're right, I should create a new answer...

Comment: And again, as I said - you're absolutely right and you are more than welcome to answer any question if you think there is a better solution.

Comment: That cold war remain unnoticed from ages xD