# How to enable swipe only on a particular view in Android ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with 3 pages and a button in each page. I can swipe anywhere on the page to go to next/previous page. How can I make the pages to swipe only when I swipe on that button but not anywhere on the page.

I have tried setting `.setClickable(false)` and `setEnabled(false)` on all the views and set it true only on button in the page layout. But still I am able to swipe anywhere on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should disable swipe on the hole viewpager with a custom viewpager.

and then detect the swipe gesture in the view that you want.

Comment: In the custom viewpager, is there any possibility to get current page and its layout in `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`, so we can enable touch only when the view is button(got from layout).

Comment: getCurrentItem() gives you the current page,
may be you can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073465/ontouchlistener-in-viewpager

Comment: Hi I have fixed it myself. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the responses. But I have fixed it myself.

I created a boolean flag in Custom ViewPager and setting it to true whenever button is touched (in button `onTouchlistener`). In Custom ViewPager `onTouchlistener`, if boolean is true, i am enabling the swipe and vice-versa.

And I am resetting the boolean to false whenever the swipe reaches either end. `onPageScrolled()` in Custom ViewPager is useful to detect whether it is swiped to either end.